# Searching inside XML documents in PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath, psql

So I currently have a very simple table using psql that looks like this:

```
Table "public.test"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |             Default              
--------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 id     | integer |           | not null | nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass)
 blah   | xml     |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

And currently has this data:

```
id |       blah       
----+------------------
  1 | =juego_Tipo1.xml
(1 row)
```

The file "juego_Tipo1.xml" looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Gamificacion Id="1">
<titulo>NomTitulo</titulo>
<autor>NomAutor</autor>
<preguntas tipo="Tipo1">
<pregunta EmpiezaPor="" comodin50="" id="preg_0" sol="A">
<temaPregunta/>
<enunciado numLineas="3">Este es el enunciado 1</enunciado>
<respuesta num="1" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta A</respuesta>
<respuesta num="2" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta B</respuesta>
<respuesta num="3" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta C</respuesta>
<respuesta num="4" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta D</respuesta>
<pista id="1" numLineas="numLineas"/>
</pregunta>
<pregunta EmpiezaPor="" comodin50="" id="preg_1" sol="B">
<temaPregunta/>
<enunciado numLineas="3">Enunciado 2</enunciado>
<respuesta num="1" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta A 2 </respuesta>
<respuesta num="2" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta B 2</respuesta>
<respuesta num="3" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta C 2</respuesta>
<respuesta num="4" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta D 2</respuesta>
<pista id="1" numLineas="numLineas"/></pregunta></preguntas></Gamificacion>
```

What I'm trying to do is to check if any of the elements inside "respuesta" is "Respuesta A". If so, I would like to return the name of the file (or files) that satisfy that condition.

I've tried to use the `xpath(xpath, xml [, nsarray])` function but it throws this error:

```
ERROR:  could not parse XML document
DETAIL:  line 1: Start tag expected, '<' not found
=juego_Tipo1.xml
```

I'm assuming this is because the function only works if the content inside "blah" is xml, not the xml file.

Is this possible? If not, how should I approach this problem?

The Postgresql I'm currently using is 10.15.

I've created the table using this command:

```
create table test(id serial primary key, blah xml);
```

And I've populated the table using these commands:

```
\set test = 'juego_Tipo1.xml'
INSERT INTO test(blah) values (:'test');
```

Note: "juego_Tipo1.xml" should be a file with the content shown above that exists in the current directory.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your DB version.

Comment: You can not just specify the name of an extarnal file, you should to load it somehow. For example: `select xpath('Gamificacion/preguntas/pregunta/respuesta/text()', pg_read_file('/tmp/foo.xml')::xml);`

Comment: The external file is loaded into postgresql using the last two commands. I don't know what else is missing.

Comment: The last two commands loads the file name, not its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is not as simple as it seems at first sight, at least for me. Following is the process to replicate and solve it as I understand it, though maybe wrong. If not correct at least I hope it will be the first step in the right direction or give you some clues of the way to approach it, because in the question you didn't even try.

1.- Create input data in temporary directory.

```
mkdir -p /tmp/stackoverflow/{initdb,xmlfiles} && cd /tmp/stackoverflow
```

2.- Edit sql file with your favourite editor:

```
vim initdb/setup.sql
```

and add:

```
create table test(id serial primary key, blah xml);

insert into test(blah)
values
('/xmlfiles/juego_Tipo1.xml'),
('/xmlfiles/juego_Tipo2.xml');

create function file_with_correct_answer(file text)
returns table(filename text) as $$
begin
    file := quote_literal(file);

    create temp table xmldata (data text);
    create temp table t (filename text);
    execute 'insert into t (filename) values (' || file || ')';
    execute 'copy xmldata from ' || file;
    return query
       with t2(fn, linexml) as (select t.filename, string_agg(data, '')::xml from xmldata cross join t group by t.filename)
       select fn from t2 where xpath_exists('//respuesta[text() = "Respuesta A"]', linexml);
    drop table xmldata;
    drop table t;

end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

3.- Create two xml files to check the success and fail conditions:

```
vim xmlfiles/juego_Tipo1.xml
```

with data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Gamificacion Id="1">
<titulo>NomTitulo</titulo>
<autor>NomAutor</autor>
<preguntas tipo="Tipo1">
<pregunta EmpiezaPor="" comodin50="" id="preg_0" sol="A">
<temaPregunta/>
<enunciado numLineas="3">Este es el enunciado 1</enunciado>
<respuesta num="1" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta A</respuesta>
<respuesta num="2" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta B</respuesta>
<respuesta num="3" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta C</respuesta>
<respuesta num="4" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta D</respuesta>
<pista id="1" numLineas="numLineas"/>
</pregunta>
<pregunta EmpiezaPor="" comodin50="" id="preg_1" sol="B">
<temaPregunta/>
<enunciado numLineas="3">Enunciado 2</enunciado>
<respuesta num="1" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta A 2 </respuesta>
<respuesta num="2" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta B 2</respuesta>
<respuesta num="3" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta C 2</respuesta>
<respuesta num="4" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta D 2</respuesta>
<pista id="1" numLineas="numLineas"/></pregunta></preguntas></Gamificacion>
```

and

```
vim xmlfiles/juego_Tipo2.xml
```

with data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Gamificacion Id="1">
<titulo>NomTitulo</titulo>
<autor>NomAutor</autor>
<preguntas tipo="Tipo1">
<pregunta EmpiezaPor="" comodin50="" id="preg_0" sol="A">
<temaPregunta/>
<enunciado numLineas="3">Este es el enunciado 1</enunciado>
<respuesta num="1" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta E</respuesta>
<respuesta num="2" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta B</respuesta>
<respuesta num="3" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta C</respuesta>
<respuesta num="4" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta D</respuesta>
<pista id="1" numLineas="numLineas"/>
</pregunta>
<pregunta EmpiezaPor="" comodin50="" id="preg_1" sol="B">
<temaPregunta/>
<enunciado numLineas="3">Enunciado 2</enunciado>
<respuesta num="1" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta A 2 </respuesta>
<respuesta num="2" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta B 2</respuesta>
<respuesta num="3" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta C 2</respuesta>
<respuesta num="4" numLetras="5" numLineas="1">Respuesta D 2</respuesta>
<pista id="1" numLineas="numLineas"/></pregunta></preguntas></Gamificacion>
```

4.- Use a docker container for Postgresql:

```
docker container run --rm -it \
--name stack-overflow \
-p 5432:5432 \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=black \
-v /tmp/stackoverflow/xmlfiles:/xmlfiles \
-v /tmp/stackoverflow/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d \
postgres
```

5.- Use psql into the container:

```
docker run -it --rm --link stack-overflow:postgres postgres \
psql -h postgres -U postgres
```

6.- Execute the query (`blah` field should be `text` type by the way) with `psql` client:

```
select file_with_correct_answer(cast(blah as text)) from test;
```

that yields:

```
 file_with_correct_answer  
---------------------------
 /xmlfiles/juego_Tipo1.xml
(1 row)
```